# Remove vertical spacing in wrapfigure (above/below hrule)

Tags: vertical-alignment, wrapfigure, vspace

I want to use **wrapfigure** to contain an (align) environment. How do I remove the excessive vertical spacing above and below the \rule commands without using \vspace? I don't understand where this space comes from in the first place.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \rule{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}
    \captionof{model}{MODEL \hfill[LP]}
    \rule{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}
    \begin{align}
        1 = 1
    \end{align}
    \rule{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

This is my current output:

[image]

I already set

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
```

in the beginning of the document. This successfully removes space around the align environment.

I want the hrules to wrap the caption tightly and symetrically. Furthermore, I want the top and bottom padding equal to the \columnsep setting, i.e left and right padding.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:**

Got there. I got this result with:

```
\captionsetup[model]{skip=0.2em, labelsep=period}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
```

and

```
\vspace{-1.3em}
\captionof{model}{MODEL \hfill[LP]}
```

**Still, for some reason \vspace always feels like a dirty hack to me. I would feel better if the linebreak after the caption would not be produced in the first place. Is the use of \vspace to be recommended, in general?**

[image]

Comment: See "Edit". I would still apperciate some thoughts on using \vspace. Is there a way to achieve the same without this command?

Comment: Wrapfig adds `\intextsep` above and below (same as `figure [h]`).  Also, `\rule` takes up `\baselineskip` by itself, while `\hrule` does not.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks a lot! Based on your comment, I went back and replaced rule with hrule. Also, I removed vspace and skip in caption. I got a super clean result. I think the major issue was the \parskip preset in my document. Is there a way to surpress parskips locally rather than setting ot to 0 for the entire document? Best, Anton

Comment: Changes inside groups such as {...} or \bgroup ...\egroup are (normally) local to the groups.